# Phonegap - Android - display only pictures in gallery/photos

Tags: android, image, cordova, camera

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(captureSuccess, onFail, {quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
```

**mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,**

```
        correctOrientation: true,
});
```

I am allowing only pictures by setting MediaType as Picture.
This works and display only pictures in gallery/photos in some android phones (eg:Samsung Prime (version4.4.4))
but in some android phones (eg:Samsung Core (version 4.4.2) videos are also displaying in gallery/photos

Please suggest solutions to display only pictures in gallery/photos

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It seems that you have to find either a different plugin or modify this plugin depending on it's license that allows modifications or not.